# Excel keyword exact match from list of keywords in dataset

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007, export-to-excel

I am struggling to create a formula on matching the exact list of keywords to a dataset. I have tried many formulas but seems like nothing is working. My requirement is to detect keywords from the list of keywords mentioned in column 'R`and data set is present from column`B`to column`N`. If suppose there are two keywords found in` row 2`then it will give me`True`value and name of those two keywords that are found. Also if keyword is`BAT` and in data set we have something like BATMAN then it should not detect Batman for keyword BAT.

Formula I tried
`=IFERROR(INDEX($R$2:$R$5,MATCH(TRUE,SEARCH($R$2:$R$5,B2)>0,0)),"Not found")`

[image]

Comment: I have tried searching alot of them, but noe of them were able to solve this BAT and BATMAN match issue. Formula mentioned will match batman also for a keyword BAT

Comment: So do one search for "BAT" and another for "BATMAN" then subtract.

Comment: Can you share sample data of examples of expected good results and sample of data of wrong results?

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question)